# AWS nodejs lambda persist output of asynchronous call in JavaScript object

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

It's a silly question perhaps, but I spent quite sometime trying to resolve but not able to get the data.

In the below function checkMailCount, I have an object called test with a function in it to assign the value to mails. The value assigned from res.on('end') to this test.mails via mailCount is not retained/persisting.

```
'use strict';

const https = require('https');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    let session = event.session;
    let request = event.request;

    if (request.type === "something") {
        if (request.name === "blah blah") {

            let emailCount = checkMailCount(session, callback);

            context.succeed(callback(null, emailCount));
        }
    }

    function checkMailCount(session, callback) {

        let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages? 
        access_token = $ {
            session.user.accesstoken
        } & q = "is:unread"
        ';

        let test = {
            mails: "",
            mailCount: function(val) {
                this.mails = val;
            }
        };

        let data = "";

        https.get(url, function(res) {

            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                data += chunk;
                //console.log(data);
            });

            res.on('end', function() {
                let result = JSON.parse(data);
                //result2+= result.replace('/\//g','');
                test.mailCount(result["resultSizeEstimate"]);

                // result["resultSizeEstimate"] inaccessible outside
            });

        });


        return test.mails; // This is returning undefined
    }

    //context.fail();
}
```

Below is the response JSON from gmail API

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "165f1627a53f70c6",
   "threadId": "165f000031cee15b"
  },
  {
   "id": "165f00d9e2e07737",
   "threadId": "165f00d9e2e07237"
  }
 ],
 "nextPageToken": "10349401829330188334",
 "resultSizeEstimate": 2
}
```

I need to return the value of result["resultSizeEstimate"] from the function checkMailCount. The value of result, result["resultSizeEstimate"] is available inside res.on('end', f(){**It is available here**}) but not outside.

I tried this in VS code not as lambda, I was able to do it by other means. Its sort of hard to unit test lambda functions. Is there a way, I can send the email count to context.succeed(callback(null, emailCount)) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I don't see any global objects in this code except for `const https`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot edited my question :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's a fundamental issue with callbacks in this code. It is not possible for `checkMailCount` to behave like you want it to in its current form. `checkMailCount` is asynchronous. JavaScript has a few different ways to deal with asynchronous code. The oldest is what you're doing here, [callbacks](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee). Next is [promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) and finally [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await). This code is probably easier to write if you switch to async/await. That said, if you want to keep using the callback pattern you're gonna have to ya know, use them.

Instead of passing lambda's callback to `checkMailCount` you should pass your own.

```
checkMailCount(session, function(err, result) {
    // result === result.resultSizeEstimate
    // Call your lambda callback from within this function
});


res.on('end', function() {
    let result = JSON.parse(data);
    test.mailCount(result["resultSizeEstimate"]);
    callback(null, result.resultSizeEstimate)    
});
```